# What can the rest of the World do to stop Israel-Palestine war?

Tags: armed-conflict, israel, united-nations, palestine

Not talking about the past but the present. Right now, the situation in Palestine has gone really really bad.

I don't know what can be done on our part but there has to be something that we can do. I have seen petitions on Causes and Avaaz but they're closed.  There are so many powerful countries and then there is the UN, but still the violence goes on. Despite being in the 21st century, is there nothing that can be done? A petition to the white house or something else?

Comment: I think if there were a definite answer to this question, then we'd known. As there may not be, I think it's primarily opinion based and should be closed. but if nobody else is voting to close I'll at least try to answer.

Comment: Can you give an example of petitions being closed on Causes and Avaaz? I can't find anyone mentioning on Twitter that any Palestine-related petitions on Avaaz have been closed. https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=Avaaz%20closed%20-dolphins%20-dolphinaria&src=typd

Comment: This type of speculation is not the type of content that SE does well with.  this is better suited to internet forums than a serious Q&A Site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy. The "War"  - which I assume you meant *[Operation Protective Edge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Protective_Edge)* - was caused by one and only one factor: Hamas, which runs Gaza, firing rockets at Israeli civilians from Gaza territory (the indirect but root cause of the conflict is Hamas's official strategy of elimination of Israel, as for example stated by Ismail Haniye, e.g. see [here](http://www.palwatch.org/main.aspx?fi=157&doc_id=6024))

UPDATE 1: This was just spectacularly confirmed when Israel declared unilateral 24-hr ceasefire (2014/07/27)... during which 7 more rockets were fired at Israeli cities.

UPDATE 2: Since then, HAMAS fired a barrage of rockets at Israeli cities during EVERY ceasefire, both unilateral and "mutual".

Moreover, the official stated goal of the operation is to prevent rocket attacks and tunnel-based terrorist acts out of Gaza.

All that the world needs to do to stop this war is to:

1. Take away all of the rockets in Gaza
2. Devise a reliable way to prevent more rockets from being smuggled into Gaza.
3. While at it, destroy all existing tunnels that Hamas dug to carry out terror acts in Israel (tunnels leading from Gaza TO Israel) - such as [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Rosh_Hashanah_Terror_Tunnel_Plot). And prevent further shipments of humanitarian aid - including money, cement and other construction materials - from being used to construct terror-purposed tunnels instead of houses for people in Gaza,

... Of course, to achieve goal #1 and #3, the world would need to do 100% of what Israel's doing in *Operation Protective Edge*; and to achieve #2, recreate the much-criticized blockade of Gaza that Israel is enforcing right now.

Another option to achieve #2 is to punish the countries that supply the rockets or money for rockets to Hamas (Quatar, Syria, Iran).

Another alternative to #1 and #2 is to prevent said rockets from ever being shot at Israel (just like USA has rockets but doesn't have the tendency to shoot them at Mexico or Russia). Given the official ideology and stated goals of Hamas, that may be a tad bit more difficult than ensuring they have no rockets in the first place.

References: Stratfor analysis of Israeli-Palestinian situation.

Comment: Everyone, these comments were interesting, but really should bein chat.  Move the discussion there, please!

Comment: Giving a negative vote because the text contains a lot of absolute (and highly biased) statement with no reliable sources to beck it up with.

Comment: absolutely biased. Do tell us when was Hamas formed. And what exactly was Israel doing in the years leading to creation of Hamas. Hence the negative vote. while answering, an answerer is expected to tell both sides of the story.

Comment: Take away all the rockets while keep Arming the Israeli state to teeth. Prevent more rockets from entering into Gaza aka strengthen the blockade which is already decimating the civilians living in open air jail named gaza. And end the aid to Gazan people and also their ways out of that hell. Bravo! Listen mate. Only the dead roll over. Living resist with whatever means are available to them. Attacks on civilians are wrong by Hamas but you also do't care about deaths of thousands at hands of Israel so what really is the difference?

Comment: @NSNoob - you may want to bother reading the first paragraph. **The difference is that Hamas has official goal to destroy Israel and official tactics to fire at civilians on purpose**. (and another official tactics of violating Geneva convention and deliberately placing their own military targets in the middle of their own civilians, which is the cause of 99% of Palestinian civilians' deaths since Israel only fires on known military targets). If you make Hamas stop attacking Israel permanently somehow, the next day on there will be zero Gaza deaths due to Israel.They only occur in self defense

Comment: Hamas is just a by-product of decades of brutality of Israelis so don't use Hamas as excuse for blatant propaganda. When there's no one willing to take up the cause of a whole people where are they to turn to? Anyone who is willing to stand up for them. It's funny that you expertly went around the chronology of Israeli occupation and birth of hamas. Monsters will give birth to monsters, no surprises there. That's exactly why your answer (Or opinion) is biased and far from the true picture.

Comment: Israel has never bothered to avoid civilian casualties. Israel has never bothered to observe any international law. Explain the mass exodus and cultural & actual genocides of the Palestinians way before Hamas even existed. Of course you can't so goodluck going on about ineffectual unguided rockets which are nothing more than crackers & how on the strongest militaries in the world with Missile shield feels threatened by it.

Comment: If there is to be peace in the region, both sides have to accept their guilt and crimes. Only by doing so can they build confidence in good-will and commitment of each other. Clamoring on about how one of the most powerful countries in the world is the victim at hands of a bunch of AK-47 armed men is not going to help anyone. Afterwards two state solution is the way to go

Comment: @NSNoob - are you even remotely familiar with the concept of cause and consequence? Israel didn't start the blockade because it hated Gazans. It started blocade **after, and because of** Gaza smuggling in rockets to be fired at Israeli civilians and other weapons. "Both sides" only works when both sides desire aggression. Not when one side is doing self defense

Comment: Funny that you should bring "Cause and consequence" up. So, Are you? Let's see the causes. Creation of Israel without consent of the native people by Western Powers, Expansion of Israeli territory by encroaching further inland called settlements, Expulsion of natives and denial of the right to return, Day-to-day harassment and systematic genocide (Actual, political, economical & cultural) of the natives. As a result of course there are consequences. "Both Sides" Definitely doesnt work when one side is hell bent on aggression based on greed, lies, deception and tyranny.

Answer (score 3):

Returning to the Israel/Palestine borders by UN and establishing the democracy for Palestinian people to have their state. and finishing the siege of Palestine and treating them like other free countries.

Also this is the solution from Bennis:

> Bennis has suggested that a solution to the Israeli-Palestinian
>   conflict would begin with “the creation of a truly independent,
>   sovereign, and democratic State of Palestine to be constructed on the
>   22 percent of historic Palestine that Israel occupied in 1967: the
>   West Bank, Gaza Strip, and East Jerusalem.” Under this arrangement,
>   “Israel and Palestine, as equals, would jointly exchange full
>   diplomatic relations” and “Israeli settlers would be given the option
>   of moving to new homes inside Israel, or remaining in their homes as
>   citizens of Palestine.” In addition, “Jerusalem would be an open city,
>   with two separate capitals within it: the capital of Israel in West
>   Jerusalem, and the capital of Palestine in East Jerusalem.” She also
>   advocates for Palestinians' right of return to Israel.

**Reference:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllis_Bennis